# Multilingual Onscreen Keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I'm not sure where to post this so I'll post it here. If I've failed to find the right location, please let me know or delete away.

Anyways, for a while now I've been working on a multilingual, onscreen keyboard jQuery plugin for use on touchscreen devices such as terminals or kiosks. I didn't see many options out there so I thought I'd take it on. My goal of the keyboard is to support a broad range of languages and provide an easy-to-use plugin based on JavaScript / jQuery. The keyboard layout files are sourced from .klc files which are generated from Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator.

I'd love to receive any feedback and improvement opportunities on this work. With your help, we might be able to transform this into a truly valuable resource for many others!

Files can be found here:
https://github.com/srm985/mok-project/tree/master

**Working Demo:**
http://www.seanmcquay.com/mok-project/sample-keyboard.htm